# ListView scrolling not working inside scrollView. it is creating jerk

Tags: android

i have integrated listView inside the scrollView. im facing issue while vertical scrolling. how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView inside the scrollView is an bad programming practice. ListView aleary has its own scrolling functionality and you are again embedding it into the scrollView that why it is creating an jerk.

Don't use listView inside the scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll let's say listView and not whole scrollView you could try this code. However, it is not good idea to place listView inside of scrollview. Your users may find it uncomfortable.

```
yourListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.yourListView) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```